# Does Stormbreaker have the same worthiness specifications as Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-infinity-war, stormbreaker

I've seen several references to

> Groot

being worthy because he is able to handle Stormbreaker. However, to my knowledge, there is no mention of Stormbreaker having the same requirements of worthiness to wield as Mjolnir did. Have there been any explicit statements on the matter?

Comment: Probably not, since that attribute was added to Mjolnir by Odin in Thor (the movie).

Comment: "he is able to **handle** Stormbreaker" ?  Pun intended?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**No, Stormbreaker does not have the worthiness requirement.**

The Russos, the directors of the film, answered this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/avengers/status/1025589644157759488?s=21)

> Mjolnir requires worthiness, not Stormbreaker. - Russo Brothers #InfinityWar #VuduViewingParty

[image: no enchantment]

Answer (score 51):

## Not that we've seen

If you recall back to the original *Thor* movie, the enchantment was placed specifically on Mjolnir during the course of the movie by Odin, as part of his attempt to teach Thor humility and responsibility. The fact that both Thor and Loki attempted to lift it in *Thor* and were surprised to have failed also implies that the lifting aspect was specifically tied to that worthiness enchantment. Also, as we learn in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hela once wielded the hammer herself and there appeared to have been no such worthiness enchantment in place at the time.

So as far as we've seen, Stormbreaker is just a normal weapon in that regard. Theoretically it should be "wieldable" by anyone, though effectively used by Thor alone, given his powers. It's also worth noting that it does have some enchantments itself, such as the

> Theoretical/proven Bifrost powers

but that was a stated enchantment, unlike the worthiness one.

Could it have such an enchantment? It's certainly possible, but there's no evidence that would allow us to conclude such. If anything, Groot's ability to lift it could be taken as additional evidence against.

Comment: I think the only way it could possibly have a similar enchantment is if Thor added it himself off-screen, but there's not really any reason to think that he *did* do that.

Comment: Or..... Groot's just worthy.

Comment: @Dave Could be. But the evidence as it is already leans in favor of no enchantment, so him lifting really proves nothing on it's own.

Comment: I agree.  But can you imagine the awesomeness of a spin-off Groothor movie? :)

Comment: I'd add to this that its not known if there was an enchantment before the events in Thor.  Thor is quick to use Mjolnir as an unliftable weight when he gets it back later, and he was already banished to Earth when Odin put that specific enchantment on it.  I think Odin may have changed the enchantment on it somewhat, where he may have only let Thor specifically wield it before, but then changed it to the "Worthy" line we see in the movie.

Comment: @Dave the dialogue practically writes itself.

Comment: When Thor first told the guardians he was going to create a weapon to defeat Thanos, starkiller(Irv) asked why they should not all have such a weapon. Thor basically said only he could wield such a weapon, perhaps "to use it properly", though it does seem that it does not require anything to lift, given that Groot briefly lifts it to make his arm it's handle. I would like to see that explored in this answer, but still, +1

Comment: imo this is the better answer, as it is in-universe, as apposed to the out-of-universe `@Avengers` twitter account.

Comment: Or... Groot is automatically worthy or exempt because it's made of Groot ??

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, considering Groot is able to put it together, and even then it doesn't since Thanos doesn't get knocked over when he gets stabbed.

Answer (score 0):

the worthiness enchantment was specific to Mjlonir I'm pretty sure. The reason its assumed most other people can't use the Stormbreaker I think is is because of Thor's line to Quill towards the beginning of IW; he says he needs a new weapon, Quill asks why they can't all have one because the weapon could kill Thanos, and Thor says their bodies wouldn't be able to handle the power of the weapon. That's what I'm remembering at least. It's really just a matter of how powerful the user is.