# How did Captain America use this in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, avengers-endgame

How did Captain America, Steve Rogers,

> become worthy to lift and use Mjölnir and Stormbreaker

effectively in *Avengers: Endgame*?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/210860/58193) and [also related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86932/58193).

Comment: Rleated: [How did Captain America manage to do this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99651/49)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot has already answered everything for you. Talking about Stormbreaker; it was never revealed that you should be "worthy" to wield it. So the second part of your question is still kinda unanswerable.

Answer (score 42):

## He was always worthy

Steve has always been worthy to lift Mjölnir as we saw in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* he was able to move it slightly. He stopped moving it because he didn't want to show Thor up in a light hearted game.

> **GeneralBenKenobi:** Could Cap always wield Mjolnir (meaning he could have picked it up in Age of Ultron and decided not to), or did he progressively get more worthy over time?
>
> **Russo_Brothers:** Anthony: He always could. Our interpretation of the famous scene in Ultron was that when he realized he could pick up Mjolnir he quickly chose not to, because he didn't want to embarrass Thor.
>
> <sub>[reddit, r/marvelstudios, We’re Joe and Anthony Russo, directors of Marvel Studios’ Avengers: Endgame. AMA!](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/cn9lbx/were_joe_and_anthony_russo_directors_of_marvel/ew97a3u/?context=1)</sub>

It is worth pointing out that before they said this Kevin Feige answered this in a [reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bp084n/hi_reddit_im_kevin_feige_amaa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) stating that he could always lift it and was just being polite to not ruin the lighthearted moment that was that scene.

> **KrazzyDJ:** Cap lifting Mjolnir was one of the strongest (crowd-cheering) moments in Endgame. Does he become worthy in that moment or has he been worthy for a while since, say, Avengers: Age of Ultron?
>
> **KevFeige:** We think he was always worthy and was being polite in Age of Ultron.
>
> <sub>[reddit, r/marvelstudios, Hi reddit, I'm Kevin Feige. AMAA](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bp084n/hi_reddit_im_kevin_feige_amaa/enp2jrt/?context=8&depth=9)</sub>

Thor even comments something to the effect of Steve being worthy all the time with:

> I knew it!

When Steve starts using Mjölnir.

He was always worthy for the same reason as Thor became worthy of Mjölnir in *Thor*...

### Because he was standing up for others no matter the cost.

Steve put his life on the line to protect the universe and was not going to give up when all hope was pretty much lost. He's always done this in the past as well and that is why he has always been worthy. However, he hasn't tried to wield Mjölnir before now except in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* where his intentions weren't exactly worthy as mentioned above.

As I said above this is similar to Thor in *Thor* when he gives up his life to save those on Earth and becomes worthy of Mjölnir once again.

> **THOR:** Brother... for whatever I have done to wrong you, whatever I have done to lead you to do this, I am sorry. But these people have done nothing to you. They are innocents.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

---

I believe there is something in the comics to the effect of people who are only just not worthy to use it can "level up" to use Mjölnir in the time of need and so this could also have affected it here but Steve also wields Mjölnir at the end of the film to take it back so I don't think it applies here.

Comment: He's even worthier than he was back then: he challenged Thanos several times despite having little hope of surviving, he ran a support group for people after the snap, he stole Pym particles without succumbing to the temptation to stay with, or even say hello to, the love of his life.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'd say he's always had the same character as back then, it's just we've seen more of it in the recent films. I.e. he's always been as worthy as he was then internally but we haven't seen as much of it shown externally.

Comment: I get that he can wield it.. but also use thunder? I thought that was something reserved for the God of Thunder?

Comment: @JakobKleinPetersen See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/210860/58193) but in short it's down to the enchantment placed upon it. _"Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor."_

Comment: Joss Whedon was asked about that scene in *Age of Ultron* and asked his own question in reply: was Steve unable to do more than budge Mjolnir when he tried to lift it, or did he *stop* when he realized he could? Given subsequent events, including Thor's delighted yell about "knowing it", the evidence seems to be that he could have lifted Mjolnir, but out of modesty and not wanting to make the others look bad--he is Captain F'n America--he stopped as soon as he realized he could. Thor suspected as much, which is why he's happy to be proven right.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86942/21871 .

Answer (score 14):

## Stormbreaker does not carry Mjölnir's worthiness enchantment

[TheLethalCarrot's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/210876/56571) covers Mjölnir, but as far as Stormbreaker goes the same worthiness enchantment doesn't apply, as detailed in [phantom42's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192312/56571) to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186773/does-stormbreaker-have-the-same-worthiness-specifications-as-mjolnir):

> The Russos, the directors of the film, answered this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/avengers/status/1025589644157759488?s=21)
>
> > Mjolnir requires worthiness, not Stormbreaker. - Russo Brothers #InfinityWar #VuduViewingParty

In fact, this is pretty definitively proven in Endgame, when Thanos himself briefly wields Stormbreaker against Thor (assuming Thanos wouldn't be regarded as worthy nonetheless).