# Why doesn't Thanos channel Thor's lightning ability?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

If Captain America can use Thor’s powers because he is worthy of the hammer, then why doesn’t Thanos use Thor’s powers?

In [*Avengers: Endgame*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/), Thanos is seen wielding and using Thor’s axe against him, which proves that he is worthy like Captain America, but he's not seen using Thor’s ability, unlike Captain America.

It’s the same with Vision but he’s a AI/robot so he probably can’t.

Comment: I'd recommend adding some spoiler tags, not everyone has seen this film yet.

Comment: Since I answered you changed the question to ask about Captain America and not Thanos, I've changed this back so my answer still makes sense. If you want to know how Captain America can channel Thor's lightning, [see this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/210860/58193).

Comment: A related question, from a year ago, is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186773/21871 .

Answer (score 30):

## Because Stormbreaker does not have the enchantment on it that Mjolnir does.

See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192312/58193).

> The Russos, the directors of the film, answered this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/avengers/status/1025589644157759488?s=21)
>
> > Mjolnir requires worthiness, not Stormbreaker. - Russo Brothers #InfinityWar #VuduViewingParty

The reason [Captain America can use Thor's powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/210860/58193) is because of the enchantment on Mjolnir and as above that is not present on Stormbreaker.

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, **shall possess the power of Thor.**

There's also a difference between holding and deflecting something to actually ***wielding*** it.

As for Vision, do we know he can't use Mjolnir's powers or does he just not use them?

Comment: As confirmation for this, when Thor summons Mjolnir to him in Asgard, he is releaved and states with a catch in his voice "I'm still worthy!"

Comment: Ok, Thanks that makes sense.

Comment: @JesseHandley If you think any of the answers here answered this will enough to cover your question you can click on the checkmark next to the voting buttons on it to accept it.

Answer (score 8):

The worthiness enchantment is only on Mjolnir (the hammer), not on Stormbreaker (the axe). The enchantment on Mjolnir was put on it by Odin, and Odin died before Stormbreaker was forged.

As far as Vision, all we know is that he *doesn't* use the lightning ability. It does not necessarily follow from this that he *can't* use the lightning ability.

Answer (score 0):

The worthiness enchantment on Mjolnir was put on it by Odin, and Odin died before Stormbreaker was forged, so without the worthiness enchantment anyone could lift Stormbreaker.

Comment: I see what your point is here but you should [edit] it to be more specific about the lightning ability.

Comment: Are you sure anyone could lift Stormbreaker? Are we sure Thanos couldn't live Mjolnir?

Answer (score -1):

Odin put the "worthy" enchantment **on the hammer**, not on Thor.

The enchantment doesn't follow Thor around.  It only existed on Mjolnir.

Honestly, Thor would have been better off leaving Stormbreaker at home, and bringing *only* Mjolnir to the 2023 Thanos fight.  Thanos would not have been able to use it against him.