# Why did Cap get Stormbreaker in that scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

There is a scene in Avengers: Endgame where Cap and Thor call for their weapons and then Cap ended up with Stormbreaker and Thor ended up with Mjölnir. Then they swapped.

I can make sense on why Cap CAN hold Stormbreaker but why did the weapons go to the other person? Like were the weapons confused who they should be going to or something?

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Whoever calls the weapon, it goes to them (valid for both Stormbreaker and Mjolnir). It’s highly likely that Cap *called* Stormbreaker just to see if he was worthy of it too (remember, Cap doesn’t know if one had to be worthy to wield Stormbreaker). Or it could just a comical science to add a bit of laughter in an otherwise thrilling action scene .

Comment: @Shreedhar I don't buy Cap called Stormbreaker, because that leads to Thor called Mjölnir and it's pretty obvious he didn't want to use the small one which means that he did not call Mjölnir. Comical science I will buy but I am hoping for something more meaningful, if there is something

Comment: I'd guess it's because the weapons don't have brains. It's already pretty amazing they can do what they do, being an axe and a hammer. Asking them to discriminate unerringly between two equally worthy wielders simultaneously calling on them seems a bit greedy.

Comment: @MishaR I disagree with this. Apparently Mjölnir is "smart" enough to determine a person's worthiness, which is an abstract notion... It should be able to go to the one who asked for it.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum Seeing as you put the word "smart" in quotation marks, you clearly recognize that the intelligence of Mjolnir is not the same as what we usually think of as "intelligence." And I agree with that. For one thing, if it were smart in the usual sense, it probably wouldn't need to be wielded, it could just fly around killing bad guys. My guess is that in-universe concept of "worthiness" is not as abstract as that of real life.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum:   It's not the weapons that are smart; it's the enchantments.    And netiher of them ever exhibit any intelligence.   They can be summoned and they (both?) cannot be weilded by unworthies.   There's no intelligence.

Comment: Thor and him summoned their weapons at the same time and caught each other’s by accident. Makes the scene flow better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Ultimately, it was just a gag.

That much is obvious. In this situation, it was mainly just a way to break up the action, Thor demanding that he gets the bigger weapon.

That said, the origins of Mjolnir, and Stormbreaker, explain that they work in similar ways:

> Mjolnir itself has several enchantments: […] it returns to the exact spot from which it is thrown and returns to its Thor when summoned

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics))</sup>

> Beta Ray Bill's weapon, Stormbreaker, also has the same properties as Thor's hammer, Mjolnir

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill#Powers_and_abilities)</sup>

That said, Beta Ray Bill obviously does not ([directly](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill)) exist in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, so Stormbreaker is not a link to him in any way. The process of creating Stormbreaker in Infinity War was simply a way to replace Mjolnir.

> "I'm gonna hold it open."
>
> "That's suicide."
>
> "So is facing Thanos without that axe."

Over the years, "summoning" Mjolnir (and by extension, Stormbreaker) has become ambiguated into "Thor calls his hammer", with little more than that for explanation. There is no real explanation as to *how* he calls it, or what he thinks, or feels when it happens. So it's anyone's guess. My only suggestion is that it might be that both Cap and Thor call the weapons, and based on their proximity, and the angle of approach that the weapons have, it'd probably work smoother to have them arrive at the wrong person, rather than bump into each other on arrival (though that would probably be arguably just as funny).

Comment: So long as it's made clear that Stormbreaker doesn't have the same worthiness enchantment as Mjolnir.

Comment: I can buy the gag thing because that's probably what it was but I definitely don't agree with the angle of approach thing because I am pretty sure they arrive at the person criss crossed which means they could of gotten to the right person easily. I be happy to accept this answer if you can remove that part

Comment: Also, it is known that the weapons will fly to the caller thru any obstacle

Comment: @Möoz *"Whosoever holds this axe, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Beta Ray Bill"*

Comment: [Stormbreaker in the MCU is not mentioned to have the same enchantment(s) as the one in the comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186773/21267)

Comment: Worth noting that Thanos briefly wields Stormbreaker as well, which implies that either Thanos is considered worthy or Stormbreaker does not have the same enchantment. I'm inclined to believe the latter.

Comment: I think it doesn't have the same enchantments as they were put on Mjolnir in the first Thor movie and nothing like that happend to Stormbreaker. However as Thor explained normal person couldn handle Stormbreaker as it is to powerfull. And as we know Thanos is quite powerfull himself.

Comment: Stormbreaker in the MCU has no enchantment, it was made in Endgame and in no scene does it receive any enchantments. Technically, anyone can hold it except if you are not powerful enough, you be dead

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Mjolnir gave Cap the ability to summon Uru weapons.

My theory: When both Thor and Cap called for the weapons in that scene, they were calling the ones they received. It's easily possible that in the heat of the moment Cap was aware of Stormbreaker's location and Thor was aware of Mjolnir's location, but not vise versa. That gives the chance to do the weapon swap joke. Now, the real question is how is Cap able to even summon Stormbreaker. He can summon Mjolnir because he is worthy, but Stormbreaker doesn't have the worthiness enchantment on it. So, that brings up the question, how does Thor summon Stormbreaker without the enchantment and how did he summon Mjolnir before Odin put the enchantment on it? I think all weapons made from Uru by the Asgardian's personal blacksmiths automatically come with the ability to be summoned by anyone in the Allfather bloodline. Notice how Odin could summon it away from Thor. Might also play a part in why Hela could catch it so easily after just coming back from imprisonment and nowhere near full power. When Cap weilded Mjolnir he possessed the power of Thor. One of those powers is the ability to summon royal Asgardian weapons. Cap wasn't holding Mjolnir when he summoned Stormbreaker and the enchantment does specifically say they have the power of Thor when holding the hammer. I think they stretched it for the MCU and made it so they still have the power of Thor for a short while after wielding Mjolnir.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a couple months since this got answered, but I have a new theory that, after looking at the Endgame scene again, I think is confirmed.

### Both Stormbreaker and Mjolnir have the same 'call' enchantment on them

We know that they don't have the exact same enchantment as only those worthy of Mjolnir can wield it. And we also know that the enchantment *doesn't* exist on Stormbreaker as even Thanos is able to hold it and almost kill Thor with it.

However, actively calling it seems to be a different scenario than actually wielding it. I'd be willing to bet that you must be worthy to actually call *both* weapons, (Thanos/everyone else can't call Stormbreaker) but you don't need to be worthy to *use* both weapons, only Mjolnir.

Now how does this answer the question? Well if both weapons have the same 'call' enchantment on them and if both Thor and Cap call *a* weapon (doesn't matter which one), it'll first look in the general direction of where it's being called from. So Cap called *a* "Thor-worthy" weapon and happened to get Stormbreaker (which was in the direction Thor just threw it) and Thor did the same in the *opposite direction*.

You'll also notice in the scene as soon as he calls Stormbreaker, once it's in his hand, he does a double take (and so does Thor). Both are visibly confused at what just happened. They both called weapons but they didn't call weapons *specifically*.

You can see it more clearly in this time-stamped video